# react ref returns undefined in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the element via using ref in componentDidMount, but it returns undefined.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined**

When this question had appeared at the first time, I used setTimeout function to make sure the element I was referring to is mounted. Like the code below:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.map.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    this.animate()
}, 0)
```

But I still get the same problem occasionally. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? Thank you so much. : ).

And if anything is unclearly, please comment below since I am not a native speaker.

---

This is how I ref a dom.

```html
<div style={{ width, height, position: 'absolute' }} ref={(element) => { this.map = element }} />
```

Comment: put the code of  where ref is defined

Comment: you can refer the link https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html to understand ref in react.

Comment: can you share your entire code in codesandbox

Comment: `this.map` is `undefined`. What is `this`?  I think it's not an array to has a `map` function

Comment: your this.map is undefined, where are you using ref here?